# overloading constructors

Tags: java

I have a 3 questions on overloaded constructors:

1.On the line marked line 1, 
   I am calling an overloaded constructor but the compiler doesn't resolve the call,
     is there something else I need to do?

2. On the line marked with a 2,
   The compiler complains that the "this()" needs to be the first statement in the 
   method, when it is. What's with that?
3. If I am writing an overloaded constructor, and I haven't overridden the default constructor do I need an explicit "this();" in the overloaded constructor, if i want to execute the behavior of the default constructor, or is it included in all constructors for "free"?

.

```
class JavaSnippet {


public static void main(String[] args) {

          String MenuItemName="Coffee";
          double MenuItemPrice=1.0;
          Item MenuItem;
     //1-> MenuItem=new Item(MenuItemName,MenuItemPrice);// Get "cannot find symbol"
    }
}         

 class Item {
    String name;
     double price;

      public void  Item(String InName, double InPrice)   {
// 2-> this();// get "call to this must be first statement in constructor"


     name=InName;
     price=InPrice;
     }

}
```

Comment: maybe it is too late already but i can not see an error there. hm. never mind... nevertheless, please dont use capital letters at the beginning of reference names, it is a matter of style of course. but you will soon see it is easier to distinguish between class names and other stuff. a common way of naming style is something like: class names - capital letter at beginning, reference - small letters, constants - capital letters ...

Comment: ahhh found one - dont write "void" in front of item constructor, this should do both errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Constructor has a method signature.
The constructor of item should be

```
public Item(String InName, double InPrice) { ... }
```

and not

```
public void Item(...)
```

And your second question:
If you want to call the other (not overriden, but explicitely defined parameterless) constructor, you need an explicit call to `this()`. If you want to call a constructor from a super-class, the call is `super()`.

Answer (score 3):

Currently you are not defining a constructor. It should not have a return type (yours has `void`). So:

```
public Item(String InName, double InPrice) { .. }
```

Then, calling `this()` will not work again. When you define a constructor with arguments, the default (no-arg) constructor is "lost". So you can't call it. And in your case - you don't need it.

(Also note that variable names in Java should start with lower-case (by convention))